# Issues in receiving emails through Email Router in Dynamics CRM

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, email-router

I have configured a Email router for my CRM 2016 online version. I have created both incoming and outgoing profiles for our company email client ( @xyz.com).

In Email router configuration Wizard, I loaded the users from CRM organization successfully, and assigned them incoming and outgoing profiles and Test access is passed.

In CRM online, I created mail box for that particular user. While doing "test and enable mailbox", both incoming and outgoing statuses are "failure".

Now If I send email from CRM, it was being sent successfully. Incoming emails are behaving differently in the below scenarios:
1. Sent an email to personal mail id from company's email web client. Replied to that email from my personal email. The reply is received in CRM System
2. Sent an email from my personal mail id to mail in Email router profile, not received in CRM system.
3. Sent an email from CRM system to my personal email id, replied to that. The reply is not received in CRM system.

When I opened our company's email client, The new email was being received and then it is vanishing from the Email client within few seconds( I think it is being taken by the email router) but I am not able to see it in CRM. I did all the necessary configurations in CRM personal options, system settings regarding email.